# Rails - Using Bootstrap datetimepicker form, date not arriving in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the bootstrap datetime picker to work with my rails program.  Here is the form I am using, it's using simpleforms:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@event, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :title %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
  });
</script>
    <%= f.input :date, as: :custom %>
    <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: {rows: "5"} %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the :custom definition in simpleforms

```
  def input
text_field_options = input_html_options.dup
hidden_field_options = input_html_options.dup

text_field_options[:id] = "datetimepicker1"
text_field_options[:class] = 'input-append date form-horizontal'
text_field_options['data-date-format'] = I18n.t('date.datepicker')

hidden_field_options[:id] = "#{attribute_name}_hidden"

return_string =
  "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, text_field_options)}\n" +
  "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, hidden_field_options)}\n"
return_string = '<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date form-horizontal">
<input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text">
<span class="add-on">
  <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>
```

'
    return return_string.html_safe
  end

In my Events Controller, I have this command to log value of event.

```
Rails.logger.info ("debug:" + @event.to_yaml)
```

And when I run form to create an event, and check log this is what I see:

```
debug:--- !ruby/object:Event
```

attributes:
  id:
  title: starky me salsa
  description: salsa me swiftly
  location:
  date:
  attendance_type:
  group_size:
  created_at:
  updated_at:
  user_id: 1

The title + description come through fine, but the date: is blank.  Any suggestions you might have would be much appreciated, I am very new to this, and I'm on the about 2 days of struggling with this, I just recently figured out how to do the logging which allowed me to trace it back here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this part:

```
return_string =
  "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, text_field_options)}\n" +
  "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, hidden_field_options)}\n"
```

is skipped since you redefine the variable next:

```
return_string = '<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date form-horizontal">
<input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text">
<span class="add-on">
  <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>'
```

The text input with the appropriate attributes doesn't render so nothing is being posted when you submit.

Also, if you are going to combine these two values and render them, it will result to two elements with the same id (datepicker1).

Comment: ah cause it goes through that hidden field? Is there somewhere I can read about that?  I wasn't aware that I needed a hidden field in order to post the data?  (sorry if this is really basic)

Comment: No problem! When you submit a form, input values are those sent back to server. And in rails case, if your input has "name" attribute: "foo[name]" then in your controller this value will be under params[:foo][:name] (your params will look like {foo: {name: "avalue"}}). You should read how does your jQuery plugin is used. Normally, it should provide a way to assign the datepicker to an input and all the extra div/hidden etc stuff should be done automatically, with no extra effort from you.

Comment: hmmm, thats good to know about the params, and name attribute.  Here is the [datepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) site.  I'm thinking the API section down at the bottom is maybe what you are talking about.  I did not understand it however, and thus was trying to merge the html into simpleforms framework.  Can I use that API section to create form?  Also it seems like none of their examples use a hidden form?

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question with rails, simple_form and bootstrap datepicker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19018373/2238268)

I have included my answer with a working implementation below:

---

I also needed to get this working and support multiple locales that do not use US centric date formats, eg: en-AU (Australia) which has the date format dd/mm/yyyy.

## The Problem

Rails expects the date format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` from the browser, yet you want to display the date in the user's locale.  Whilst the date control allows you to specify the format for display it does NOT allow you to separately specify the format to be sent back to the server.

## The Solution

Build a hidden input field that sends the correct format back to your rails server.  I do this with with a custom simple_form input control that builds both the date-picker input field and a hidden field, and use some javascript to convert to the rails date when the input control changes.

The upshot is you can have a nice bootstrap date-picker in rails and use it with simple_form as follows:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker %>
```

Or to use a long date format:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker, input_html: { format: :long } %>
```

## Implementation

Create or edit the following files:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**config/locales/en-AU.yml**

```
en-AU:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: "dd MM, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
      long: ! '%d %B, %Y'
```

**config/locales/en-US.yml**

```
en-US:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "mm/dd/yyyy"
      long: "MM dd, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: ! '%B %d, %Y'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
#= require bootstrap
#= require bootstrap-datepicker
#= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

Alternatively, **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

**app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  # convert bootstrap-datepicker value to rails date format (yyyy-mm-dd) on our hidden field
  $(document).on 'changeDate', '.bootstrap-datepicker', (evt) ->
    rails_date = evt.date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (evt.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + evt.date.getDate()).slice(-2)
    $(this).next("input[type=hidden]").val(rails_date)
```

**app/inputs/bootstrap_datepicker_input.rb**

```
class BootstrapDatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    text_field_options = input_html_options.with_indifferent_access
    format =  text_field_options.delete(:format)
    hidden_field_options = text_field_options.dup
    hidden_field_options[:class] = text_field_options[:class].dup # so they won't work with same array object
    hidden_field_options[:id] = "#{attribute_name}_hidden"
    text_field_options[:class] << 'bootstrap-datepicker'
    text_field_options[:type] = 'text'
    text_field_options[:value] ||= format_date(value(object), format)
    set_data_option text_field_options, 'date-format', I18n.t(format, scope: [:date, :datepicker], default: :default)
    default_data_option text_field_options, 'provide', 'datepicker'

    return_string =
      "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, text_field_options.to_hash)}\n" +
      "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, hidden_field_options.to_hash)}\n"
    return return_string.html_safe
  end

protected

  def default_data_option(hash, key, value)
    set_data_option(hash,key,value) unless data_option(hash, key)
  end

  def data_option(hash, key)
    hash[:data].try(:[],key) || hash["data-#{key}"]
  end

  def set_data_option(hash, key, value)
    hash[:data].try(:[]=,key,value) || (hash["data-#{key}"] = value)
  end

  def value(object)
    object.send @attribute_name if object
  end

  def format_date(value, format=nil)
    value.try(:strftime, I18n.t(format, scope: [ :date, :formats ], default: :default))
  end
end
```