# Bootstrap datepicker default value simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am using the bootstrap date picker to enable selection of dates in a form using simple_form_for. For example

```
  <%= f.input :payment_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" } %>
```

My date picker uses the format of dd-mm-yyyy

I would like to set today's date as the default value in the form using simple_form_for, any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<%= f.input :payment_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker", value: Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') } %>
```

Another format to it is: (working with active admin gem)

```
f.input :date, as: :date_picker, :input_html => { :value => Date.today}
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue with bootstrap-datetimepicker and this works for the date & time picker as well.

Comment: In Rails 4 `<%= f.text_field :payment_date, as: :string, class: "datepicker", value: Date.today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>`

Comment: @rAzOr That one was of great help

Answer (score 8):

**You can also use this gem:**
https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

on your **gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**then bundle install and restart rails server**

then add this line to **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

and add this line to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
 //= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

**and to use this in your form:**

```
<%= f.text_field :payment_date, :id => "datepicker", :value => Date.today %>
```

**and add this javascript on the same view of your form**

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I also needed to get this working and support multiple locales that do not use US centric date formats, eg: en-AU (Australia) which has the date format dd/mm/yyyy.

## The Problem

Rails expects the date format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` from the browser, yet you want to display the date in the user's locale.  Whilst the date control allows you to specify the format for display it does NOT allow you to separately specify the format to be sent back to the server.

## The Solution

Build a hidden input field that sends the correct format back to your rails server.  I do this with with a custom simple_form input control that builds both the date-picker input field and a hidden field, and use some javascript to convert to the rails date when the input control changes.

The upshot is you can have a nice bootstrap date-picker in rails and use it with simple_form as follows:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker %>
```

Or to use a long date format:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :bootstrap_datepicker, input_html: { format: :long } %>
```

## Implementation

Create or edit the following files:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**config/locales/en-AU.yml**

```
en-AU:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: "dd MM, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
      long: ! '%d %B, %Y'
```

**config/locales/en-US.yml**

```
en-US:
  date:
    datepicker:
      default: "mm/dd/yyyy"
      long: "MM dd, yyyy"
    formats:
      default: "dd/mm/yyyy"
      long: ! '%B %d, %Y'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
#= require bootstrap
#= require bootstrap-datepicker
#= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

Alternatively, **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker-rails
```

**app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  # convert bootstrap-datepicker value to rails date format (yyyy-mm-dd) on our hidden field
  $(document).on 'changeDate', '.bootstrap-datepicker', (evt) ->
    rails_date = evt.date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (evt.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + evt.date.getDate()).slice(-2)
    $(this).next("input[type=hidden]").val(rails_date)
```

**app/inputs/bootstrap_datepicker_input.rb**

```
class BootstrapDatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    text_field_options = input_html_options.with_indifferent_access
    format =  text_field_options.delete(:format)
    hidden_field_options = text_field_options.dup
    hidden_field_options[:class] = text_field_options[:class].dup # so they won't work with same array object
    hidden_field_options[:id] = "#{attribute_name}_hidden"
    text_field_options[:class] << 'bootstrap-datepicker'
    text_field_options[:type] = 'text'
    text_field_options[:value] ||= format_date(value(object), format)
    set_data_option text_field_options, 'date-format', I18n.t(format, scope: [:date, :datepicker], default: :default)
    default_data_option text_field_options, 'provide', 'datepicker'

    return_string =
      "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, text_field_options.to_hash)}\n" +
      "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, hidden_field_options.to_hash)}\n"
    return return_string.html_safe
  end

protected

  def default_data_option(hash, key, value)
    set_data_option(hash,key,value) unless data_option(hash, key)
  end

  def data_option(hash, key)
    hash[:data].try(:[],key) || hash["data-#{key}"]
  end

  def set_data_option(hash, key, value)
    hash[:data].try(:[]=,key,value) || (hash["data-#{key}"] = value)
  end

  def value(object)
    object.send @attribute_name if object
  end

  def format_date(value, format=nil)
    value.try(:strftime, I18n.t(format, scope: [ :date, :formats ], default: :default))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor addition to what Andrew Hacking said: your coffeescript will also want to capture the `clearDate` event.

```
$ ->
  # convert bootstrap-datepicker value to rails date format (yyyy-mm-dd) on our hidden field
  $(document).on 'changeDate clearDate', '.bootstrap-datepicker', (evt) ->
    rails_date = if evt.date? then evt.date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (evt.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + evt.date.getDate()).slice(-2) else ''
    $(this).next("input[type=hidden]").val(rails_date)$(document).on 'changeDate clearDate', '.bootstrap-datepicker', (evt) ->`
```